# Cropping PDF files cannot crop out text for text extraction (textract and pdfminer)

Tags: python, text-mining, pypdf, pdfminer

I’m using the python library `PyPDF2` to crop many PDF files to cut out the useless information on top and bottom of academic papers (i.e. page numbers and journal information at the bottom). Then I used the library `textract` to extract the texts from the cropped PDF files to txt files. However, the output txt files still contains the cropped out information despite the cropping.
This also applies to `pdfminer`, another text extraction library (not OCR). It seems that for text extraction, as opposed to OCR, the text cannot be eliminated by simply cropping. Can anyone explain why this is the case? Any idea on how else to eliminate useless information in PDF files for text extraction?

Comment: Crop only hide the information from being viewed. The content is still inside the PDF file. I am not familiar with `textract` nor `pdfminer`. Please check if these two libraries allow you to OCR from viewable contents instead of all contents. Alternatively, take our everything and use text and regular expression to remove those information.